# All paragraphs identation gets lost after adding figures

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

```
\section{Approach}
First Paragraph ..some text Shown in Fig.1 some text.

\hfill \break
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{systemArchitecture.png}
\captionof{figure}{System Architecture}

\hfill \break
Paragraph ..some text

Paragraph ..some text
```

All remaining paragraphs after the figure have lost the identation:

[image]

How can I add indentation to the first line of the paragraph?

Comment: you have not said but you are presumably using the `caption` package which documents that captions should be in a group, or preferably a minipage

Comment: what is the intention of `\hfill \break` ? it seems strange markup for a latex document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle to add line breaks before and after figures

Comment: it is a weird way to do that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what is the right way to do it?

Comment: figures are normally in a `figure` environment and  end of paraagraph is marked by a blank line. It is very hard to guess what "it" is that you are trying to do as you have not said what you expect the code to do and you have not posted it in a form that anyone can run to see the problem. The main question in the title is fixed by adding a group, as in the first comment, for the rest I can't really guess

Comment: By "adding a group" I presume is meant something like, after a blank line, insert `\begingroup`, and after the actual caption, add `\endgroup` followed by a blank line.

Answer (score 3):

`\hfill\break` has no place in any TeX document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


aaa


\hfill \break
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 

Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

As you see it looks a bit like a non-indented paragraph (The cause of the "lost" indentation in the question). However the paragraph has an indent but the first line is all white and *only* has the indentation and the hfill space. It looks a bit like vertical space but is not, it is a line of the paragraph, so is not dropped at a page break, and counts as line 1 for widow and orphan control. "Paragraph" is not indented as it is the 2nd line of the paragraph, not because indentation has been suppressed

A figure has no effect on the indentation of paragraphs in the main text flow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}


aaa

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{System Architecture}
\end{figure}

Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 

Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 
Paragraph some text Paragraph some text 

\end{document}
```